# SPARK DataFrame: alternative scala code for hive max(case) statement with group by

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe with four columns (id int,name String, mobile String,phone String)

I need alternative way to implement the logic in hive query to scala code.

Hive query is :

```
SELECT id AS member_id
,max(CASE WHEN name = 'Mrs.' THEN mobile ELSE NULL END) AS mobile
,max(CASE WHEN name = 'Dr.' THEN phone ELSE NULL END) AS phone
from temp1
group by id;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write:

```
dataFrame.registerTempTable("temp1")
val result = sqlContext.sql (here put same SQL as in question)
```

Or in Spark 2.0 it will be:

```
dataset.createTempView("temp1")
val result = sparkSession.sql(here put same SQL as in question)
```

Alternatively, you can use Dataset API:

```
val mobileUDF = udf {
    (name : String, mobile : String) => if (name == "Mrs.") mobile else null;
}
val phoneUDF = udf {
    (name : String, phone: String) => if (name == "Mrs.") phone else null;
}

dataset.withColumn("newMobile", mobileUDF($"name", $"mobile"))
    .withColumn("newPhone", phoneUDF($"name", $"phone"))
    .groupBy($"id")
    .agg(max(col("newMobile")), max(col("newPhone")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.groupBy('id).agg(
  max(when('name === "Mrs.", 'mobile)).alias("mobile"),
  max(when('name === "Dr.", 'phone)).alias("phone")
)
```